# xsd:unique in a Java class

Tags: java, xml, xsd

The `xsd:unique` constraint in my schema defines primary key and foreign key for few elements.

Though the schema does not throw any error.

While generating java class `xsd:unique` is not added.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xsd:import namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" schemaLocation="msdata.xsd" />
    <xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="subroot">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                   <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="set">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:any processContents="lax" />
                    <xsd:choice>
                      <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Held">
                          <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:attribute name="_attr1" use="required" type="xsd:integer" />
                            <xsd:attribute name="_attr2" use="required" type="xsd:integer" />
                          </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Asses">
                          <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:attribute name="_attr2" use="required" type="xsd:integer" />
                            <xsd:attribute name="_attr3" use="required" type="xsd:NCName" />
                          </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                      </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:choice>
                  </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:unique name="PK_Held" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
                  <xsd:selector xpath="xsd:Held"></xsd:selector>
                  <xsd:field xpath="@_attr1"></xsd:field>
                </xsd:unique>
                <xsd:unique name="PK_Asses" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
                 <xsd:selector xpath="xsd:Asses"></xsd:selector>
                 <xsd:field xpath="@_attr2"></xsd:field>
                 </xsd:unique> 
                <xsd:keyref name="FK_Held_Asses" refer="PK_Asses">
                 <xsd:selector xpath="xsd:Held"></xsd:selector>
                 <xsd:field xpath="@_attr2"></xsd:field>
                 </xsd:keyref>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: JAXB doesn't enforce validation rules. To enforce validation rules, you need to specify the XSD schema when parsing the XML, with validation enabled.

Comment: @Andreas I think that qualifies as an answer rather than a comment. Maybe post it with a little snippet on how to create a Schema instance and set it on the unmarshaller?

Comment: Thanks Andreas,one additional info---this is a vendor provided xml and we generated the schema out of it. They are sending the unique constraints in the xml itself, hence the parsing fails at `<xsd:unique>` tag.

Comment: @G_H Answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAXB doesn't enforce validation rules.

To enforce validation rules, you need to specify the XSD schema when *parsing* the XML.

Assuming you're asking the `Unmarshaller` to parse the XML for you, e.g. you're not unmarshalling a DOM node, you do it like this:

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile); // file or URL

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance();
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
unmarshaller.setEventHandler(handler); // To specify how validation errors should be handled
Object obj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source);
```

This is described in the javadoc of [`Unmarshaller`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html):

> **Validation and Well-Formedness**
>
> A client application can enable or disable JAXP 1.3 validation mechanism via the `setSchema(javax.xml.validation.Schema)` API. Sophisticated clients can specify their own validating SAX 2.0 compliant parser and bypass the JAXP 1.3 validation mechanism using the [`unmarshal(Source)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal-javax.xml.transform.Source-) API.
>
> Since unmarshalling invalid XML content is defined in JAXB 2.0, the Unmarshaller default validation event handler was made more lenient than in JAXB 1.0. When schema-derived code generated by JAXB 1.0 binding compiler is registered with [`JAXBContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html), the default unmarshal validation handler is [`DefaultValidationEventHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/helpers/DefaultValidationEventHandler.html) and it terminates the marshal operation after encountering either a fatal error or an error. For a JAXB 2.0 client application, there is no explicitly defined default validation handler and the default event handling only terminates the unmarshal operation after encountering a fatal error.

Comment: Thanks for the post Andreas.